# Backup Sql Express

Tags: c#, database, backup, sql-server-express, database-backups

I would like to be able to run an on demand backup of a .Net MVC app's SQL Express 2008 database to eg a flash stick plugged into the machine running the app.

I tried

```
QuickstemDataContext db = new QuickstemDataContext();
 string quickstem_path = Path.Combine(save_path, "quickstem.backup");
 db.ExecuteCommand(string.Format("BACKUP DATABASE {1} TO DISK = '{0}' WITH COMPRESSION;", quickstem_path, db.Mapping.DatabaseName));
```

But get the exception

Database 'quickstem' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally

I am using the following connection string.

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\quickstem.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Do I need to attach the DB using something like Express Management Studio and give it a name etc.  Ideally I want to keep the app deploy very simple without having to setup sql management studio etc.  Can this attaching be done another way or can a Backup be done with out needing to attach

I tried giving it the full path of the .mdf file instead of the database name but got a syntax error on c:

Comment: What does this question have to do with C# or ASP.NET-MVC?

Comment: Apart from the fact that SQL Express is the database that ships with ASP.NET and the code he has written is in C# - absolutely nothing :)

Comment: I was trying to avoid getting an "Install this application" answer, ie wanted people to know I wanted the mvc app doing the backup on request not something else. As the title is now it looks like the other Backup Sql Express questions on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that if you add `Database=Quickstem` to your connection string, your backup code will work just fine.

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\quickstem.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Database=Quickstem
```